# What do I press to move all of a certain item to a chest?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, nintendo-switch

How do I move multiple stacks of the same item from my inventory to a chest or from a chest to my inventory on Nintendo Switch?

Comment: To My knowledge, there is no way to move multiple stacks of items on any version of Minecraft.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, actually!

- Console: double-click whatever button you use to select an item
- PC: hold shift and click the item
- Pocket Edition: double-tap the item.

I don't know if it works if your stacks are full (64 items), though. Probably not since the methods I mentioned are for gathering scattered items, like iron ingots in a blacksmith villager's chest.

Comment: Lmao thanks to whoever did the edit :) Couldn't figure it out